# Entity Framework 6 : no Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I get this error:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

But there is an `<entityFramework>` section in the `app.config` file.

My context class:

```
public class NorthwindContext:DbContext
{
    public NorthwindContext():base(nameOrConnectionString:"NorthwindContext") 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

My `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

How can I fix? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Remove the version 5.0 references